# Creating New Objects Inside a Loop

Tags: java, arrays

Okay, let me be more specific on what is happening. The code through each iteration of the for loop runs fine in that, code not included here, inputs are taken in from a user which are stored in the "Ball" object which is then stored in ballStorage. I have a to print in the for loop to show me what the "Ball" object at ballStorage[i] contains and the results are accurate. However, when I print out the results of the entire array's content after the for loop, every single "Ball" object in the array is overwritten with the last "Ball" object's values. I then checked to see what happens if I add a new "Ball "object outside of the for loop to ballStorage.length-1 which is empty and find that "Ball" object overwrote all the other "Ball" objects in the array. Please help and sorry for not being clear about what is happening.

```
for(int i = 0; i < ballStorage.length-1; i++){

 ballStorage[i] = new Ball();
 System.out.println("\n Ball number "+i+": \n"+ballStorage[i].toString());

}
```

Comment: Creating new object within loop doesn't make sense in your case. Anyway you are populating ballStorage with the same ball every time.

Comment: You are storing different Ball object for every element of the arry. But as you are not setting any values, the value of every Ball should be same.

Comment: @RustamUmarov The OP is creating a new `Ball` object on each iteration.  They all have the same state, so given a correctly implemented `equals()` and `hashCode()` they would _appear_ the same.

Comment: @babymario123  You are creating distinct `Ball` objects.  However, we cannot tell why you think you are storing references to the same object in every array member.  Please post the code for the `Ball` class.  Perhaps since the ball objects all have the same internal state they only _appear_ to be the same object?

Comment: maybe you can add a new variable as : long seal = System.currentTimeMillis();

Comment: @ShedomWei or may be just give those balls an ID. `ball.setId(i + 1);ballStorage[i] = ball;`

Comment: The last update does not really clarify anything.  We need to see the actual _evidence_ supporting your assertion, as well as the source code for the `Ball` class. How do you ***know*** it's the same ball instance in all array slots? Without that your question is like asking your mechanic to diagnose your car's inability to start without opening the engine compartment.  If you want help, please help us to help you by providing the necessary information.

Answer (score -1):

if you want an array that store objects do this:

```
class Ball {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Ball[]obj =new Ball[5];
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            obj[i]=new Ball();
        }
         for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(obj[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I didn't much gets your question. But you can access the object of an array inside the loop by index after assigning its new object. let say

```
for(int x=0; x<ballStorage.Length; x++){
   ballStorage[x] = new Ball(x); //assign value of the ball inside constructor
   //access the ball 
   ballStorage[x].bounce(); //example

   // or you can do this, access previous ball
   if(x > 0)
     ballStorage[x-1].bounce();
}
```

Comment: Please read the question carefully, you have merely posted a side comment that bears no relationship to the question.  This is not the way StackOverflow works, please read [answer]